# Expression blend for animations

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, 3d, expression-blend

I am trying to create a short animation of an object rotating in 3D space..I have all my images ready..I would like to know how I can change from one image to the other without the transition moves being shown

Thank you

Edit: What i mean is that instead of having a bouncing ball which all i need to do is move the ball in each frame, what if i had and object that in every frame I used a different image: eg. person facing forward, person facing facing right, etc...how can i do it without the image being shown as being dragged from the screen?

I hope I'm making sense

Comment: What exactly do you mean by without transition moves? Can you edit your question and elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I whant to advise you look at [Principles of Microsoft Silverlight Animation](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T12F) video by Jeff Paries on mix09. I shure it usefull and comprehensive overview of Silverlight animations.

Comment: this video is exactly what I needed. Thanks